How to update Grub to 2.12 in Lunar Lobster
I have an issue upgrading an old install of Lunar Lobster. See also here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1159167/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-23-04-to-23-10-when-do-release-upgrade-blocks-due-to-grub
Due to a bug in Grub, the system won't upgrade:
Due to a bug in grub, this system cannot be safely upgraded at this
time.
See https://launchpad.net/bugs/2039172.

It was suggested to ask here, on ask Ubuntu, specifically how to resolve this. Perhaps by upgrading Grub manually some way. As I can find no PPA's with Grub for Lunar, next step would be to build from source. But would that work? Is there another way?

Download the iso of 24.04 and fresh install. It is much simpler than upgrading from an outdated release where the upgrade does not work due to grub.

Unfortunately, that is not an option.

Why is it not an option? Do you not have physical access to this computer?

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

We cannot help you make changes to an EOL system (23.04 is EOL), but you've not provided specifics as to your system.  If it was me (a Desktop user) I'd likely non-destructively re-install 23.10 over your system thus achieve the release-upgrade via unclean re-install if it was a Desktop  (depending on your setup, that may or may not be possible with 24.04 Desktop).    Server installs have added complexity for that approach (clean install & restore data is usually easiest there).

FYI:   You can ask for specific help with your do-release-upgrade if you ask it on this site; 23.04 to 23.10 release-upgrades are on-topic on this site, but changes to an existing EOL release alas are not.   Stack Exchange rules however do prevent the same question on multiple SE sites, questions are intended to be moved/migrated or closed/re-asked

I am aware that it is end  of life, and I would have reinstalled, replaced etc. if it were an option. But this is a remote system.
The EOL status being the problem itself, not having a grub update.
In any case, adding a ext4 partition for boot solved the issue.

The solution was to simply reformat a boot partition at ext4 fs.
That worked to allow the upgrade.
